# Bad Request (#400) Parámetros requeridos ausentes: id : yii 2 framework

Tags: php, yii2

Hola a todos me sale este error en yii2 framework cuando intento pasar un parametro $id a la accion de un controlador para crear una venta, este $id lo quiero usar para traer otros datos que ya estan guardados en la tabla de ventas

Este es mi controlador para crear una nueva venta, cuando intento traer los datos me sale el error del titulo, ¿que puedo hacer?.

```
public function actionPrincipal($id){

    $model =  new Venta();

    $placa = Venta::getById($id);

    $materiales=MaterialForm::getMateriales();

    $clientes = ClienteForm::getLista();

    $detalle=new DetalleForm();

    $tipo=[0 => "Efectivo", 1 => "Por cobrar", 2 => "Retiro Mat."];

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        $model->fecha=explode(",", $model->fecha)[1];

        $model->saldo=0;

        if ($model->tipo==1) {

            $model->saldo=$model->total-$model->cancelado;

        }

        if($model->tipo==2) {

            $model->saldo=$model->total-$model->cancelado;

        }

        if ($model->create()) {

            $id_venta=$model->getLastInsertedId();

            $lista_cant=Yii::$app->request->post('cantidad');

            $lista_precio=Yii::$app->request->post('precio');

            foreach ($lista_cant as $key => $value) {

                $detalle->id_material=$key;

                $detalle->id_venta=$id_venta;

                $detalle->cantidad=$value;

                $detalle->precio=$lista_precio[$key];

                if ($value==0) {

                    continue;

                }

                $detalle->create();

            }



            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success','Registrado exitósamente.');

            return $this->redirect($url = (Yii::$app->user->identity->rol=="VENTAS") ? ['view-placa', 'id' => $id_venta]:['principal']);

        }

    }

    $model->tipo=0;

    $model->_usuario=Yii::$app->user->id;

    $model->_registrado=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $model->fecha=Yii::$app->formatter->asDate(date_create(Venta::getById($model->getLastInsertedId())->fecha),'php:l,d-m-Y');

    $pagina=(Yii::$app->user->identity->username=='contador')?"puntoVenta/principal_admin":"puntoVenta/principal";

    return $this->render($pagina, [

        'placa' => $placa,

        'materiales'=>$materiales,

        'venta' => $model,

        'clientes' => $clientes,

        'tipo'=>$tipo,

    ]);
```

}

Ahora este es **mi vista** para traer los datos ya guardados pero no me deja, me sale parametro requerido $id, ahora los datos que intento trae son de la **variable $placa**

```
      <?= $form->field($venta, '_usuario')->hiddenInput(['value' => $venta->_usuario])->label(false) ?>

      <?= $form->field($venta, '_registrado')->hiddenInput(['value' => $venta->_registrado])->label(false) ?>

      <input type="hidden" id="txtId" value="<?= date_timestamp_get(date_create($venta->_registrado)) ?>">

      <?= $form->field($venta, 'conductor')->input(['id'=>'txtObservacion','rows' => '3','onclick'=>'getId(this)']) ?>

      <?= $form->field($placa, 'capacidad')->input(['id'=>'txtObservacion','rows' => '3','onclick'=>'getId(this)']) ?>

      <?= $form->field($placa, 'placanum')->input(['id'=>'txtObservacion','rows' => '3','onclick'=>'getId(this)']) ?>

      <?= $form->field($venta, 'observacion')->textarea(['id'=>'txtObservacion','rows' => '3','onclick'=>'getId(this)']) ?>

  </div>
```

Agradeceria su ayuda, gracias.

Comment: Puedes poner una URL de ejemplo en como haces la llamada al controlador?

Answer (score 0):

Lo más seguro es que no estás mandando el parámetro id en tu formulario.

Recuerda que puedes mandar en tu formulario parametros por GET y por POST, pero si el controller requieres un parametro entre paréntesis, entonces es necesario que le mantes un parámetro por GET como el siguiente ejemplo:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(
            ['action' => ['update-image', **'id' => $model->id**  ],                
                'options' =>['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'],
        ]); ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Si observas mi action se llama 'update-image' y estoy pasando adicionalmente un parámetro por GET "'id' => $model->id " que en ese caso es mi propio modelo, pero puedes pasar cualquier variable.

Puedes ver una explicación más completa en este link: http://tutoriales-yii2.blogspot.com/2018/06/como-agregar-un-parametro-get.html